# Register 64bit com component from 32bit wix script

Tags: windows, com, wix, 64-bit

I have WIX script that install and register 32bit COM component for IE, also I want to include into the same package the 64 bit COM component for IE without creating additional packages (didn't want to confuse user with 2 identical programs in Add/Remove panel) and I see only one variant - run action like this

[WindowsFolder]\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe 
and did't check the response of this operation

So, my installer will works both in 32 and 64 windows

question: Are there any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the registry keys for the 32-bit registration in a Component with Win64="no". That will ensure that when compiling for 64-bit, the registration stays 32-bit.